# Not showing pages of WordPress installed site on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, apache2

I have installed three WordPress sites on a WAMP localhost:

localhost/pacific_ocean

localhost/surfing_new

localhost/construction

Everything was working yesterday. Today, when I go to the above url's, the screen is blank white, and the WordPress installed site is not showing.

1.) I have checked options.php and it is pointing the site url is fine: http://localhost/pacific_ocean/

2.) I have run 'netstat -abno' on an administrator command prompt and it shows that  [httpd.exe] is running on port 80

Then I ran httpd.exe -e warn and here's what I got:

**(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs**

Is httpd.exe getting in the way of Apache running or is this another issue?

One of the sites shows /index of folders, but that's it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing ports?

Comment: How do I change ports?

Comment: I don't remember very well. Stopped using Wamp ages ago. But should be something like: https://img.raymond.cc/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/wamp_server_change_port_80.png

Comment: This will not solve the problem by itself, but it will give us more clues. Did you install any other thing since yesterday? As anything else changed on your machine and/or environment?

Comment: Nothing changed except Skype was active (not used). I used a program to see what was running port 80 and it says 'httpd.exe' using port 80 WAMP ...not sure if that is skype or what it is and how to turn it off

Comment: That'll be probably it! Either try changing Wamp apache port 80 to 8080 or something, or close (terminate) Skype and restart Wamp. Then you can open Skype again.